# RFC support on Cloud Foundry

Tags: saprfc, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

Some months ago there was no RFC support on Cloud Foundry. It was discussed here:

https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/15/step-11-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-virtual-data-model-for-bapi/

Are RFC calls supported in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

It is not yet possible to transfer calls that use the RFC protocol via the Cloud Connector from an application running on Cloud Foundry.

I will update this answer once support for RFC on Cloud Foundry becomes available.

Comment: The s4sdk also support Bapi-calls, are they also affected? Is RFC support already part of the roadmap? And if yes, when is planned availability?

Comment: Yes, this also applies to BAPI calls as they are using RFC as protocol when targeting SAP S/4HANA on-premise via Cloud Connector.